# How to put double line under a text with different color and space beetwen them using HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I am new in HTML, I want to put double line under a text like below [image]. However,  I cant do it. I tried to use hr but it did not give me the result I want. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.underline {
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  text-decoration-style: double;
}

.border {
  border-bottom: double 3px;
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="underline">This is some text with a double underline.</div>
<br>

<div class="border">This is some text with a border double..</div>
```

Comment: I cant give space between  text and underline right? When I am using text decoration

Comment: u only mentioned of using hr.. that is why explained this method, next time onwards try to explain more in questions asked : )

Comment: i have added another easy method by which u can give space between text and underline

Comment: No Problem Here to help :)

Answer (score 2):

```css
#yourBlock {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  width: fit-content;
}
#yourBlock::before {
  content: "";
}
#yourBlock::after {
  position: relative;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="yourBlock">Block</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this simple way :)) :

```css
.box {
  width: fit-content;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <span>BLOG</span>
</div>
```